# Restrict zero at the first character only in angular 2+. (expected output- 10101)

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-template

How to restrict zero at the first character only in the input field (expected output is like 10101)?

This is my way of doing.

HTML markup:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-4" #check (keypress)="isInteger($event)">
```

Typescript `.ts` file:

```
@ViewChild("check") inputFileld:ElementRef;

isInteger(event)
{
    if(event.key=='0' && !this.inputFileld.nativeElement.value)
    {
       return false
    }
}
```

With this trick, I'm not able to enter zero at first character but the problem is, write some number in the input field and select all the value and press zero that time zero is triggering.

Comment: Change the type to number and use pattern https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp to limit the character via regex? Try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-4" #check  id="myText"   (keypress)="isInteger($event)">
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
isInteger(event) {

    var ctl = document.getElementById('myText');
    var startPos = ctl['selectionStart'];

    if (startPos == 0 && String.fromCharCode(event.which) == '0') {
      return false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.